# MySQL — Query possible without three SELECT?

Tags: mysql

Happy New Year's, everyone!

I'll jump right into it. I've inherited a project that includes a very large database. Some tables are upwards of 285.6GiB.

One of the larger tables is user-ratings. The table has the following columns (simplified):

- `from` — `VARCHAR(19)`
- `reason` — `VARCHAR(512)`
- `stars` — `TINYINT`
- `timestamp` — `TIMESTAMP`
- `to` — `VARCHAR(19)`

Currently, users can check the ratings of other users. THis shows a summary of their ratings given, received, as well as their entire last 5 ratings received. To do this, we'd currently use the following queries (simplified):

```sql
# First query — ratings given from the user
SELECT Avg(`stars`),
        Min(`timestamp`),
        Count(*),
        Count(DISTINCT( `to` ))
INTO   avgStarsGiven, firstRatingGivenAt, totalRatingsGiven,
        totalUniqueRatingsGiven
FROM   `ratings`
WHERE  `from` = user;

# Second query — ratings received by the user
SELECT Avg(`stars`),
        Min(`timestamp`),
        Count(*),
        Count(DISTINCT( `from` ))
INTO   avgStarsReceived, firstRatingReceivedAt, totalRatingsReceived,
        totalUniqueRatingsReceived
FROM   `ratings`
WHERE  `to` = user;

# Third query — get the last 5 ratings to the user
SELECT * FROM `ratings` WHERE `to` = user ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Is it possible to retrieve all of this information without having to go over the entire table 3 times?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: The table and version are below:

```sql
# 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
CREATE TABLE `ratings` (
  `no` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` varchar(19) NOT NULL,
  `to` varchar(19) NOT NULL,
  `reason` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `stars` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`no`),
  KEY `i-ratings-from` (`from`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `i-ratings-to` (`to`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `i-ratings-from-to-timestamp` (`from`,`to`,`timestamp`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk-ratings-from` FOREIGN KEY (`from`) REFERENCES `users` (`user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk-ratings-to` FOREIGN KEY (`to`) REFERENCES `users` (`user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: show what output you want

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table ratings;` and `select version();`

Comment: why the INTO?  are you doing this in a stored procedure?

Comment: It might not be able to do cleanly as the first queries effectively return 1 row and the last 5 rows. What would the output be when these are combined? If the last 5 ratings are denormalized into a single value (ie. group_concat), is that acceptable, and how does it change the previous answer?

Comment: @ysth — I've added the `show create table ratings;` and `select version();`

Comment: "without 3 selects" -- No.  Indexing is the performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to go over the entire table in any of these queries, if you define indexes on the columns `from` and `to`. When you look for a person by name in a telephone book, do you read the entire book every time?

```
ALTER TABLE ratings
  ADD INDEX (`from`),
  ADD INDEX (`to`, `timestamp`);
```

You can use EXPLAIN to confirm that it's using the index:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `ratings` WHERE `to` = <example-value> 
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 5;
```

The EXPLAIN report should show you in its `rows` field that it will examine a small subset of the rows of the table. This is one of the benefits of an index, to narrow down the search efficiently, so a query doesn't need to scan the entire table.

---

You edited your question above to add the CREATE TABLE definition.
I see that your table already has some indexes, but these indexes aren't tailored very well to the queries you show. You might like to review my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Also I see that some of your indexes are defined with the `INVISIBLE` option, which means the optimizer won't use these indexes. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-indexes.html for details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll definitely check out your links! As I mentioned before, I inherited this project and am trying to think of any way to better the performance of the project.

Comment: Sure, it's a common task to inherit a project and be faced with the fact that optimization has been neglected for some time. As I wrote above, use EXPLAIN to analyze your queries, and make sure the indexes are designed to support those queries.

Comment: Upon inspecting the rest of the tables, it looks like all of the indexes are invisible. I'll follow along with your links. I imagine just making them visible and better tailoring them to queries should help drastically. Thanks again!

Comment: Another question, since I'm seeing this a lot — if a single column is used for a unique index, should it also have a standard index or is that redundant?

Comment: It's redundant. A "unique key" naturally also serves as an index.

Comment: When you add his indexes, Drop the index on just `(to)`; it will get in the way.